# Spring Data Redis doesn't initialize RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, javabeans

I've integrated two Spring Data modules into my application: Spring Data MongoDB and Spring Data Redis.

While the Spring Data MongoDB module is working like a charm, I'm struggling with Spring Data Redis due to issues related to wiring up the RestTemplate bean, which is necessary for interactions with Redis.

Once the Spring Boot app starts up, I'm ending up with the following error:

> ***************************  APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   com.github.wjoz.talkative.messageService.repository.redis.impl.RedisMessageRepositoryImpl
>   required a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate' that could not be
>   found.
>     - Bean method 'redisTemplate' in 'RedisAutoConfiguration.RedisConfiguration' not loaded because
>   @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: redisTemplate; SearchStrategy: all)
>   found bean 'redisTemplate'
>
> Action:
>
> Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate' in your
>   configuration.

Spring's saying that bean cannot be instantiated, though, when I debug at redisTemplate(), the bean is created and instantiated in BeanFactory (IoC Container), since the execution stops there.

I got two Spring Data modules, so Spring Data is entering the strict repository configuration mode, as it's mentioned in the logs:

> Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository
>   configuration mode!

For Spring Data Redis I'm not using neither the Repository nor the CrudRepository interfaces, instead, I've implemented it with the plain @Repository annotation due to the issues mentioned here:
[Repositories - Multiple Modules](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.multiple-modules)

I think there might be an issue with version conflicts somewhere in Spring  Boot starters. but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.github.wjoz</groupId>
<artifactId>talkative-message-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>talkative-message-service</name>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>5.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.security.jwt.version>1.0.7.RELEASE</spring.security.jwt.version>
    <spring.cloud.starter.version>1.2.3.RELEASE</spring.cloud.starter.version>
    <spring.cloud.eureka.server.version>1.3.4.RELEASE</spring.cloud.eureka.server.version>
    <oauth.version>2.0.12.RELEASE</oauth.version>
    <modelmapper.version>0.7.7</modelmapper.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <h2.version>1.4.193</h2.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.8.1</log4j2.version>
    <jackson.version>2.8.7</jackson.version>
    <apachecommons.version>2.5</apachecommons.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
     <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.starter.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data Redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data MongoDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Starter Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Starter Security OAuth 2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${oauth.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Test Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security module for JSON Web Token support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.jwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Eureka for service registration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.eureka.server.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ModelMapper for DTO/Domain object conversion -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
        <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Embedded Redis for integration tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Boot Hot Swap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j 2 API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j 2 Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j 2 YAML support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${apachecommons.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <!--<resource>-->
        <!--<directory>src/main/resources</directory>-->
        <!--<filtering>true</filtering>-->
        <!--<excludes>-->
        <!--<exclude>*.jks</exclude>-->
        <!--</excludes>-->
        <!--</resource>-->
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**BaseAppConfig - Configuration Class**

```
    @Configuration
    @Profile({ApplicationProfiles.DEVELOPMENT, ApplicationProfiles.PRODUCTION})
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = Packages.MONGO_REPOSITORY)
    public class BaseAppConfig {

        /**
         * Configures the Java client for Redis.
         * @return the Java Redis client object
         */
        @Bean
        public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
            return new JedisConnectionFactory();
        }

        /**
         * Provides the central class of the Redis module for Redis interactions.
         * @return the Redis interaction class
         */
        @Bean
        public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
            RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
            redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
            return redisTemplate;
        }
    }
```

**MongoMessageRepository**

```
    public interface MongoMessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, String> {

    }
```

**RedisMessageRepositoryImpl - Where I attempt to autowire RestTemplate**

```
@Repository
public class RedisMessageRepositoryImpl implements RedisMessageRepository {

    private static final String KEY = "Message";
    private final RedisTemplate<String, Message> redisTemplate;
    private HashOperations<String, String, Message> hashOperations;

    @Inject
    private RedisMessageRepositoryImpl(RedisTemplate<String, Message> redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Message message) {
        hashOperations.put(KEY, message.getId(), message);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I've added the main MessageServer class which is rather straightforward:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = Packages.COMPONENT_ROOT)
@EnableFeignClients
public class MessageServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessageServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share the main class code?

Comment: @reply

I've added the main class to the original post :)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I've managed to figure out what was the cause of the issue.
The bean was instantiated in the IoC container, but the problem occurred during attempt to auto wire it in RedisMessageRepositoryImpl because of my two silly mistakes:

First of all, I accidentally used the **private** modifier instead of **public** in

```
 @Inject
    private RedisMessageRepositoryImpl(RedisTemplate<String, Message> redisTemplate) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }
```

so the bean itself couldn't be instantiated even if it was marked with @Repository.

I had to remove the generic declaration of RedisTemplate:

```
private final RedisTemplate<String, Message> redisTemplate;
```

to

```
private final RedisTemplate redisTemplate;
```

In this way, the bean is now autowired without any issues as well as found in IntelliJ and all is fine.